# Flash Professional CS6 or Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-cs6

Recently I have been looking at Flash Professional CS6 and Flash Builder 4.6. I am trying to figure out what would be best for me, but I have no idea. When I create my apps I do all of the graphics and coding, with many graphics, and many many lines of code :). Also I am into nice interfaces, so I would like if it included an easy way to create interfaces.

If you could give me any recommendation for what program I should get, that would be great.

Thanks,
RMK-Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the big up side of flash pro is it facilitates developers working with artists.  it's a nice IDE for artists to build their graphics and animations into but it does it in a way everything is accessible to the developers.  if you *are* the artist there's far less upside.  they're both capable of outputting all the same features into the same end product, but flash builder gives you more and better tools to do it with.  if you can only get one, get flash builder...